# DB conexion Mysql Xampp

Tags: java, mysql, xampp

I have a problem.

I already make a DB with `PHPmyadmin` using Xampp to generate a localhost but when i try to connect to my DB the IDE never make the connection and never send me some kind of error, it's like the IDE just keep "thinking" I don't know if I'm making the connection in a wrong way, i hope you can help me.

thats the class where I make the connection

```
package restaurantelospavorreales;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author luisricardo
 */
public class DB_Conecttion {
    public Connection Conexion(){
        Connection Con = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/pavorreales", "root", "");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se presento el error: " + e);
        }
        return Con;
    }
}
```

Here is where I make the instance of the class `DB_Connection`

```
package restaurantelospavorreales;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**

 * @author luisricardo
 */
public class BuscarProducto {
    public LinkedList Producto(int Identificador, String Tipo, int Cantidad, int Mesa){
        LinkedList Datos = new LinkedList();
        Datos.add(Mesa);
        String Query;
        Query = "SELECT ID, Nombre, Precio FROM '" + Tipo + "' WHERE ID = " + Identificador ;       //Se construye el Query
        //Se realiza la conexion
        try {
            ResultSet Res = new DB_Conecttion().Conexion().createStatement().executeQuery(Query);

            Datos.addLast(Res.getString(1));
            Datos.addLast(Res.getString(2));
            Datos.addLast(Res.getString(3));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error en la conexion a la DB :" + e);
        }

        return Datos;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Which IDE are you using?
That sounds more like an issue with the IDE being prevented a connection on localhost by a firewall or something.

Comment: i'm using NetBeans and i already turn off the Firewall and the problem continue

Comment: just when i change the string of connection it send me error

Answer (score -1):

```
public void closeConnection() {
        try {
            Conexion.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "closed the connection to database");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MySQL.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

This is my code where i printed details about the connection.

Comment: Please use English when posting on SO. Thanks!